# Quando utilizar a função do.call?

Tags: r

Dieferentemente de `lapply`, `do.call` aplica uma função em toda uma lista (que também é um `data.frame`). Considere o loop `for` abaixo:

```
set.seed(123)

for (i in 1:6) {
  assign(paste('var', i, sep = '_'), 
         runif(30, 20, 100))
}
```

Posso lançar mão de `do.call` para transformar estes vetores em um `data.frame`:

```
data_1 <- do.call(
  cbind.data.frame, 
  mget(ls(pattern = '*v'))
)
```

Mas, isso não faz sentido, pois a própria função (seja ela `cbind.data.frame`, `sum`, etc.) faria o mesmo sem a necessidade de aplicação de `do.call`. Por exemplo:

```
data_2 <- cbind.data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = '*v')))
```

Agora para a soma:

```
do.call(sum, data_2)
[1] 10826.89

sum(data_2)
[1] 10826.89
```

Pergunto:

- Em qual contexto a função `do.call` tornar-se-ia indispensável? Por quê?

Comment: Ainda não consegui parar para responder, mas a ideia central é fazer vários chamados seguidos

Comment: Um exemplo clássico é `do.call` e `rbind` para uma lista de resultados. Lembro de algumas comparações que mostravam que o `do.call` era mais rápido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `do.call` deve ser usado quando você quer passar uma lista de argumentos para uma função em oposição a passar uma lista como argumento para a função.

Ou seja, chamar  `do.call(rbind, lista)` é o mesmo que chamar `rbind(lista[[1]], lista[[2]], ..., lista[[n]])` que por sua vez é diferente de chamar `rbind(lista)` (ver ao final).

Além disso o `do.call` consegue ganhar performance em relação a outras opções.

```r
library(tidyverse)

n <- 10 ^ 4 # 10 mil

gerar_range <- function(...) {
  valores <- range(rnorm(100))
  tibble(min = valores[1], max = valores[2])
}

lista <- map(seq_len(n), gerar_range)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  do.call = do.call(rbind, lista),
  rbind = {
    res <- lista[[1]]
    for (i in lista[-1]) {
      res <- rbind(res, i)
    }
    res
  }
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#>  do.call  330.6749  354.1027  368.621  365.3997  381.5701  428.9259   100  a
#>    rbind 2611.6736 2727.6387 2828.675 2806.4544 2890.7625 3159.1669   100   b
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Veja também que por conta do assinalado no início, chamar  `do.call(rbind, lista)` e `rbind(lista)` podem ter resultados diferentes e por isso não podem/devem ser comparados. Exemplo:

```
rbind(lista[1:10])
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10] 
[1,] List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2

do.call(rbind, lista[1:10])
# A tibble: 10 x 2
     min   max
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 -2.67  2.24
 2 -2.36  2.24
 3 -2.84  2.82
 4 -2.30  2.05
 5 -3.01  2.73
 6 -2.07  2.75
 7 -2.21  2.76
 8 -3.13  2.14
 9 -2.32  1.92
10 -3.45  2.70
```